# Net core custom user property

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, asp.net-core

I'm using the default authorization in my .NET Core project. I want to check if an user is admin so in ApplicationUser.cs model I've added this:

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{

    public bool admin { get; set; }
}
```

I migrated these changes into my SQL database and I can see the 'admin' property inside the AspNetUsers table. How do I check the 'admin' property of the currently logged in user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the current user instance through the `UserManager<T>` object, which can be injected into your controller as a constructor parameter. The method `GetUserAsync` takes a `ClaimsPrincipal`, which in this case is the User of the `HttpContext`.

```
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
public HomeController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager) {
    _userManager = userManager;

    var user = _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above answer by Peter to just use the `user` variable and check for `user.admin`,  however, I strongly suggest extending your project to use a simple Role-based Authorization to simplify things in the long run. You can achieve this with the following documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles